# Renombrar archivos y carpetas a la vez

Tags: python

Buscando algo de información no encuentro dónde moverle para que me renombre archivos y carpetas a la vez usando Python. Utilizando en mi función cuando uso:

```
for nombreArch in archivosEn:
                print('Archivo encontrado: %s' % nombreArch)
                #Con .replace intercambiaremos los caracteres especiales por algún similar. La ñ puede ser cambiada por 'ni', 'n' ó 'x'.
                archNvo = nombreArch.replace("ñ","ni").replace(" ","_").replace("á","a").replace("é","e").replace("í","i").replace("ó","o").replace("ú","u")
                os.rename(nombreArch,archNvo)
                print("Los caracteres especiales fueron removidos...")
```

Sí renombra todos los archivos, pero solo los archivos. Las carpetas las deja intactas. Al querer iterar de nuevo déjandolo así:

```
for carpRuta,carp,archivosEn in os.walk(entrada):
        #Definimos nuestro entorno de trabajo.
        print("Directorio encontrado: %s" % carpRuta)
        #carps = os.chdir(carpRuta)
        for nombreCarp in carp:
            print('Carpeta encontrada: %s' % nombreCarp)
            for nombreArch in archivosEn:
                print('Archivo encontrado: %s' % nombreArch)
                #Con .replace intercambiaremos los caracteres especiales por algún similar. La ñ puede ser cambiada por 'ni', 'n' ó 'x'.
                archNvo = nombreArch.replace("ñ","ni").replace(" ","_").replace("á","a").replace("é","e").replace("í","i").replace("ó","o").replace("ú","u")
                os.rename(nombreArch,archNvo)
                print("Los caracteres especiales fueron removidos...")
            carpNva = nombreCarp.replace("ñ","ni").replace(" ","_").replace("á","a").replace("é","e").replace("í","i").replace("ó","o").replace("ú","u")    
            os.rename(nombreCarp,carpNva)
            print("Los caracteres especiales fueron removidos...")
```

Solo agarra los archivos en la raíz y solo modifica esos. Les dejó un poco más de la función usada para este caso y, si alguien pudiera orientarme, se los agradecería muchísimo.

```
def copiarContenido():
    fecha = date.today()
    entrada = input("Introduce la ubicación de la carpeta a respaldar: ")
    destino_int = input("Introduce la ubicación donde quieres dejar el respaldo: ")
    destino = (f"{destino_int}/Archivos_Copiados_{fecha}")
    print(f"La carpeta elegida es: {entrada}")
    #Copiaremos el contenido antes de ser parseado.
    todosLosArchivos = glob.glob(os.path.join(entrada), recursive=True)
    print("Archivos a copiar...", todosLosArchivos)
    for ruta_archivo in todosLosArchivos:
        ruta_destino = os.path.join(destino, os.path.basename(ruta_archivo))
        shutil.copytree(ruta_archivo, ruta_destino)
        print(f"Copiado... {ruta_archivo} -> {ruta_destino}")
    #Empezaremos a quitar espacios y demás caracteres de los nombres.
    for carpRuta,carp,archivosEn in os.walk(entrada):
        #Definimos nuestro entorno de trabajo.
        print("Directorio encontrado: %s" % carpRuta)
        #carps = os.chdir(carpRuta)
        for nombreCarp in carp:
            print('Carpeta encontrada: %s' % nombreCarp)
            for nombreArch in archivosEn:
                print('Archivo encontrado: %s' % nombreArch)
                #Con .replace intercambiaremos los caracteres especiales por algún similar. La ñ puede ser cambiada por 'ni', 'n' ó 'x'.
                archNvo = nombreArch.replace("ñ","ni").replace(" ","_").replace("á","a").replace("é","e").replace("í","i").replace("ó","o").replace("ú","u")
                os.rename(nombreArch,archNvo)
                print("Los caracteres especiales fueron removidos...")
            carpNva = nombreCarp.replace("ñ","ni").replace(" ","_").replace("á","a").replace("é","e").replace("í","i").replace("ó","o").replace("ú","u")    
            os.rename(nombreCarp,carpNva)
            print("Los caracteres especiales fueron removidos...")
```

Desde ya, muchísimas gracias.

---Edito---

He logrado reducir un poco mi código. Tal que cuando únicamente le paso unos `print()`

```
def copiarContenido():
    fecha = date.today()
    entrada = input("Introduce la ubicación de la carpeta a respaldar: ")
    destino_int = input("Introduce la ubicación donde quieres dejar el respaldo: ")
    destino = (f"{destino_int}\Archivos_Copiados_{fecha}")
    print(f"La carpeta elegida es: {entrada}")
    #Copiaremos el contenido antes de ser parseado.
    todosLosArchivos = shutil.copytree(entrada,destino)
    print(f"Copiado con éxito en {todosLosArchivos}")
    #Nos movemos a la carpeta destino.
    os.chdir(destino)
    #Empezaremos a quitar espacios y demás caracteres de los nombres.
    for carpRuta,carpetas,archivos in os.walk(destino):
        print(f"Ruta encontrada: {carpRuta}")
        print(f"Directorio encontrado: {carpetas}")
        print(f"Archivo encontrado: {archivos}")
```

En los `print()` sale esto en terminal.

```
Introduce la ubicación de la carpeta a respaldar: C:\Users\Rene\Desktop\Archivos_Origen
Introduce la ubicación donde quieres dejar el respaldo: C:\Users\Rene\Desktop\Copiados
La carpeta elegida es: C:\Users\Rene\Desktop\Archivos_Origen
Copiado con éxito en C:\Users\Rene\Desktop\Copiados\Archivos_Copiados_2022-11-08
Ruta encontrada: C:\Users\Rene\Desktop\Copiados\Archivos_Copiados_2022-11-08
Directorio encontrado: ['Excelñ', 'Hola Mundo', 'Vehículo']
Archivo encontrado: ['Circúnferencia.java', 'renombrador.py', 'text.txt']
Ruta encontrada: C:\Users\Rene\Desktop\Copiados\Archivos_Copiados_2022-11-08\Excelñ       
Directorio encontrado: []
Archivo encontrado: ['Excel 2 sql.java']
Ruta encontrada: C:\Users\Rene\Desktop\Copiados\Archivos_Copiados_2022-11-08\Hola Mundo   
Directorio encontrado: ['Adios Mundo']
Archivo encontrado: ['HolaMundo.java']
Ruta encontrada: C:\Users\Rene\Desktop\Copiados\Archivos_Copiados_2022-11-08\Hola Mundo\Adios Mundo
Directorio encontrado: ['xd']
Archivo encontrado: []
Ruta encontrada: C:\Users\Rene\Desktop\Copiados\Archivos_Copiados_2022-11-08\Hola Mundo\Adios Mundo\xd
Directorio encontrado: []
Archivo encontrado: ['jélóíú.txt']
Ruta encontrada: C:\Users\Rene\Desktop\Copiados\Archivos_Copiados_2022-11-08\Vehículo
Directorio encontrado: ['años']
Archivo encontrado: ['Vehículo.java']
Ruta encontrada: C:\Users\Rene\Desktop\Copiados\Archivos_Copiados_2022-11-08\Vehículo\añosDirectorio encontrado: []
Archivo encontrado: ['modelosñ.txt']
```

Muchas gracias por alguna respuesta.

Comment: `rename()` no crea directorios; los directorios tienen que existir antes del `rename()`.

Comment: Ya le modifiqué pero no entiendo porqué no toma los directorios ya existentes.
 `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado: 'Excel 2 sql.java' -> 'Excel_2_sql.java'`
Sale ese error. Y no entiendo por qué.

Comment: Es díficil responder sin ver la estructura de directorios con la que trabajas, ni cual es tu directorio de trabajo. Lo mejor es revisar (`print()`) los nombres que estás pasando al sistema.

Comment: Mejor usa `glob` te será más fácil

Comment: @Christian cómo se podría lograr cómo lo comentas? Gracias.

Comment: @CandidMoe Te respondo añadiendo una captura editando mi propia pregunta. Gracias.

Comment: Ahora no tengo mucho tiempo para redactar una respuesta, pero aquí te dejo la [documentacion](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) para que sepas de que hablo